# Publish json file on RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I am able to publish json files into rabbitmq using the command line API. Below are the command and parameters

```
user=guest
pass=guest
exchange=test

curl -s -u ${user}:${pass} -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d @sample_25MB.json http://localhost:8080/api/exchanges/%2f/${exchange}/publish
```

But i am not sure how to look the overview in RabbitMQ UI.